# xrandr with dual displays, problem getting back to 'simple side by side' after using larger screen with scale

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, xrandr

I'm running two displays, main HDMI1 right 1680x1050, auxiliary HDMI2 left 1280x1024, on an i5 with a Xeon E3-1200 integrated graphics.

Most of the time I use them side by side. Occasionally I want to see a 2:1 scaled 3360x2100 desktop on the right monitor, do some work, then reset it to the way it was. I am failing to be able to reset it.

I have set a couple of aliases to switch sizes of the main monitor,

```
alias x20="xrandr --fb 3360x2100 --output HDMI1 --scale 2x2 --mode 1680x1050 --panning 3360x2100"
alias x10="xrandr --fb 1680x1050 --output HDMI1 --scale 1x1 --mode 1680x1050 --panning 1680x1050"  
alias xh="xrandr --output HDMI1 --right-of HDMI2"
```

There is no need for panning *per se* but I appear to need to set it to get round the 'caged mouse' bug where the mouse is confined to the upper left quadrant of the display if I don't. I then appeared to need to set it down to get proper behaviour back at 1:1 scale.

After running x10, both displays are 1:1, but both are top left corner 0,0. When I run xh, nothing appears to change, the displays still sit at 0,0 top left. However, at this point xrandr says the desktop is 2960x1050, big enough to hold both side by side, and it will let the mouse disappear off into the void to the right. Doing a scrot confirms that the screen is 2960 wide.

I have tried many experiments to get the main display back to the appropriate offset of 1280,0 including:-

switching the aux display off before I scale by 2, then on again after I've returned
setting --pos 1280x0
setting --left-of or --right-of for the appropriate monitor
switching the main monitor off and on
just setting it to --auto
but nothing has appeared to undo whatever confusion I've created.

In the last experiment with switching the main off and on, I got the error message

```
prompt> xrandr --output HDMI1 --auto --right-of HDMI2 
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)  
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)  
  Minor opcode of failed request:  29 (RRSetPanning)  
  Serial number of failed request:  38  
  Current serial number in output stream:  38
```

So far, the only way I have been able to reset the displays back to normal side by side is to restart the PC, which is not ideal.

(edit) But I've found that a logout will do the job as well, and as a --force-logout alias will get me there from the terminal, blind, that's a workaround I'm prepared to use (/edit)

If I go into the gui screen resolution tool, I can move the screens around, but when I ask it to apply, they snap back to where they were, so this tool appears to have lost control as well.

I guess what I'm after is a command that says 'go back to your power-on state', or at least, stop panning, stop scaling, stop fb'ing. --auto doesn't seem to do that.

In some earlier experiments, I used --pos, --above and --left-of on HDMI2 and they behaved as expected, presenting the two monitors stacked or side by side. However, I had not been fooling around with --scale, --fb or --panning prior to using those.

Am I driving xrandr incorrectly, or is it evidence of a hardware compatibility problem? How do I go about systematically looking for a workaround, I feel I am totally poking and hoping at the moment?